# Can I modify Woocommerce dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce plugin on my WordPress website, and now I want to modify dashboard for users, but when I open the page i have only this [woocommerce_my_account] short code, so now I want to know where it is coming from, and how can I change it? 

So in that dashboard I want to add some new pages, tabs and videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the path `contents/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-account.php` so you can edit there.

Comment: So can you help me how can I change it? When I insert regular <h1> tag it does not wants to shows up.

Comment: Now everything is ok! I just don't know to need to make copy of folder to theme folder so now I have your-theme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php on example, and everything is fine. 
Thanks

Comment: Great. Please up vote and accept the answer if it solves your purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this free plugin to change basic things.

1. My Account Page details are shown in the form of side bars. These
   side bars are: ‘Dashboard’, ‘My Downloads’, ‘My Orders’, ‘Edit
   Account’ and ‘Edit Address’
2. Option to edit the text of the menu options.
3. Option to deactivate the menu option temporarily.
4. Option to reorder the menus.

**[Download Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-my-account-for-woocommerce/)**

Answer (score 0):

**Path** contents/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-account.php so you can edit there. as mentioned by @noman

**Custom age for the dashboard.php**

Create a folder “woocommerce” inside your theme folder
Create another new folder “myaccount” inside the “woocommerce” folder
Go to plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount and copy the dashboard.php file
Paste this file into yourthemefolder/woocommerce/myaccount folder
Now edit the text and save the file